# How to add storyboard or XIB without changing the UIScreen size

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

Since iOS 13.0 we get this warning: 
 Launch images are deprecated in iOS 13.0. Use a launch storyboard or XIB instead.

But when using a storyboard or A XIB, the app doesn't scale the same way.

when we are using a launch image:
    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds = 1024 * 768

but when using a storyboard or A XIB:
    UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds = 1366 * 1024 or other (depending on the device)

Since the other UIviewController in our app are 1024 * 768, this cause them to not scale and then not use all available screen space.

Can I make the storyboard or XIB to set UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds to 1024 * 768

Comment: It sounds like you have been ignoring different device sizes for some time; It is probably time to bite the bullet and update your app to support variable screen sizing through autolayout

Comment: You should change the `contentMode` as you need. Usually `scaleAspectFill` is same with the old launch image style but actually it depends on your preferences.